# Can't append AngularJS array

Tags: html, angularjs

I hope the title isn't too confusing.

I have an array in my `angular.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('resume', []);

app.controller('resumeCtrl', function($scope, $document) {
  $scope.projects = [
    {
        title: 'TRU Colors Brewing Co.',
        image: 'images/tcb_screenshot.png',
        url: 'https://www.trucolors.co',
        category: ['development', 'design']
    },
    {
        title: 'JOMO',
        image: 'images/jomo_screenshot.png',
        url: 'https://jeffberlin.github.io/JOMO_website/index.html',
        category: 'development'
    }
];
```

And in my HTML file I have:

```
<div class="row portfolio-preview">

  <div class="col-lg-4 text-center" ng-repeat="x in projects">

    <div class="projects tab-content active">

       <figure class="tab-pane">
         <a ng-href="{{x.url}}" target="_blank">
          <img class="img-fluid screenshot" ng-src="{{x.image}}">
         </a>                         
       </figure>

   <div class="description">

     <a href="" target="_blank">
      <h5>{{x.title}}</h5>
     </a>
   </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Now my issue is, I get the correct number of boxes to show with the titles, but nothing else displays/shows from the array. For reference, this section will have 3 options in the `nav` area and filter them out (by the `category`), assuming that's the best to do it. Can anyone see something I might be doing wrong?

The HTML code shown is the only way I've been able to at least get the `titles` to show up by using `x in projects` and the `x.image`, `x.title`, etc.

P.S.- I'm very new to Angular, but appreciate you all taking the time to help!

Comment: So what specifically isn't showing/working?

Comment: The only things that display now is the `title`. Really, I want the `title` and `image` to show, then obviously the `url` will be attached to the `title` (which isn't working either right now), and then upon selection on the `nav`, will filter them by `category`, but that's for another time. Does my answer make any sense? (I realize I'm bad at explaining)

Comment: So really, `{{x.image}}` and `{{x.url}}` aren't working

Comment: Try changing your paths in the original array to have a leading `/` slash to turn them into absolute paths instead of relative paths

Comment: you are missing a closing div tag

Comment: @floor sorry, that missing div came from me accidentally deleting it in the post, but in my actual code I am not missing one.

Comment: @Tallboy I just tried `image: '/images/image_name'` and that didn't seem to work

Comment: @jbrally can you inspect the a tag to see if your url is populated

Comment: @floor I did just get the `url`'s to work (yay)! The `images` still won't show though

Comment: @jbrally where is your images folder? and how are you serving up the app? did you just open your index.html file or are you running it in a local server?

Comment: @floor I'm just opening it in the browser right now, but it will just be run through Github pages. My folder setup has a `css, images, js` all on the same level as the `index.html`. Obviously my `angular.js` file is inside the `js` folder

Comment: @jbrally try making the image: ./images/tcb_screenshot.png

Comment: @floor I did that and when I inspect the item, it shows the `ng-src` and `src` is the devtools and the `src` shows the correct image when it's hovered, but the image itself doesn't show on the page. Could that be because I am just opening the page in the browser without a server of sorts?

Comment: @jbrally the ./ should work. remove the classes on the img tag to see if your css is making it not display

Comment: @floor AH HA! The `tab-pane` class seemed to be the issue for some reason. Thank you so much for your help! I had a feeling it was something small and stupid that was keeping it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a relative path to your images folder. The path needs to be relative to where your html file is so the browser knows where to look properly.

Add ./ in front of your image url.

```
$scope.projects = [
{
    title: 'TRU Colors Brewing Co.',
    image: './images/tcb_screenshot.png',
    url: 'https://www.trucolors.co',
    category: ['development', 'design']
},
{
    title: 'JOMO',
    image: './images/jomo_screenshot.png',
    url: 'https://jeffberlin.github.io/JOMO_website/index.html',
    category: 'development'
}
```

];

and as pointed out in the comments your css might be causing the image to be hidden or not have a width or height. So when debugging don't forget to check the css.

Comment: Thanks again @floor! Now it's time to tackle the filtering of the nav selection, wish me luck – ha!